# Changing Address

Tags: wordpress, redirect

How Can I Redirect A Page In WordPress Without A Plugin? I Need to Redirect Page [کربنات کلسیم](https://calcium-carbonate.ir/%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA-%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%85/) To /Calcium-Carbonate/ . I Don’t Know What To Do Please Help Me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly make 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886601/how-to-properly-make-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use .htaccess file and 301 redirection. Or you can use 'wp_redirect()' if needed. But .htaccess is better solution.

```
Redirect 301 /old-url /new-url
```

Answer (score 0):

used the following code .

**please paste the given function in themes function.php**

following snippet add in function.php

```
function redirect_dest() {
         if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
            ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
            isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
            $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
            $protocol = 'https://';
            }
            else {
            $protocol = 'http://';
        }

        $currenturl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $currenturl_relative = wp_make_link_relative($currenturl);

        switch ($currenturl_relative) {

            case '[from slug]':
                $urlto = home_url('[to slug]');
                break;

            default:
                return;

        }

        if ($currenturl != $urlto)
            exit( wp_redirect( $urlto ) );


    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_dest' );
```

and in switch case code please replace the following slug path :

**from slug: enter source path slug**

**to slug: destination path slug**

switch ($currenturl_relative) {

```
            case '[from slug]':
                $urlto = home_url('[to slug]');
                break;

            default:
                return;

        }
```

Similarly if your URL is;

```
https://www.example.com/05/18/some-page
```

The slug will be:

```
/05/18/some-page
```